# How do I shut down embedded Jetty (Eclipse Project)?

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, embedded-jetty

So I'm trying to embed Jetty into this Java application I'm working on but when I run it, and then subsequently terminate it, when I hover over the run button I still get a "'so and so' is still running" message and when I then when I try to re-run I get the expected NetBind Exception: Address is still in use. So how do I terminate the jetty server? Clearly terminating the program is not terminating the server for some reason.

Note: I haven't downloaded Jetty itself onto my local computer, I just invoke maven dependencies through eclipse (idk if that makes a difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html) has a `.stop()` method you can call to perform a graceful shutdown of the Jetty server instance.

Also, in Eclipse, be sure you have the "Debug View" open.

Window > Show View > Other > Debug

That will show you the list of running processes that any Eclipse plugin started for you.
You might think you terminated it, but it might still be registered as running.